# OffsetDateTime java8 ojdbc8 oracle insert cet to cest problem

Tags: oracle, java-8, ojdbc, offsetdatetime

Hello I have a problem with insert OffsetdateTime with correct timezone I have string 20110401000000000 then I do convertion to OffsetDateTime  like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dft =
                    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                            .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                            .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
                            .toFormatter();

            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(pDateTimeString, dft);
            OffsetDateTime of = OffsetDateTime.of(dateTime, ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));
```

and I get 2011-04-01T00:00+01:00 - everything is good
now I do insert to database

```
 ps.setObject(3,of);
```

and in my datebase I see

[image: red is wrong]

is it convert in cest

curiosity -------------

if date 2021-03-03T00:00+01:00

[image]

it is correct put in database

-- my settings of my connection

c.getDefaultTimeZone() -> Europa/Zurich

c.getSessionTimeZone() -> Europa/Zurich

Thank you for help

Comment: It is because **Daylight Saving Time** starts on 28-Mar-2021 at 02:00. Check https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/switzerland